# How to resize the org-agenda date header?

Tags: elisp, org-mode

I am trying to customize `org-agenda-list`, but the date header turns out to be huge. Does anyone know how to configure the font size of the date header? I followed https://blog.aaronbieber.com/2016/09/24/an-agenda-for-life-with-org-mode.html to do the customization.

Example of huge date header:

[image: example of huge date header]

Comment: I found that it is somehow caused by leuven theme. By disabing leuven, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

you can navigate to that line in the agenda and then press M-x (Meta Button and x at the same time). In the bottom bar of emacs you then should write

```
customize-face
```

Emacs will directly show the face which you are on (org-agenda-date-today and org-agenda-date).

Here you can then change the size via the value "Height". In leuven theme, i assume the unit "Scale" is used. Maybe something like:

Height: Value Menu Scale: 1.6

Here you can change the font size and then press "Apply and Save".

Answer (score 0):

I use usually, the following snippet, just put it in your `init.el` or `.spaceamcs`.

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'org-agenda
  (custom-set-faces
   '(org-agenda-date-today
     ((t (:inherit org-agenda-date :weight bold :foreground "YOUR_COLOR" :height 1.2))))))
```

- YOUR_COLOR: for example I use `#FFD3E8`.